# What kind of WebGL optimization couldn't be done using Three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm learned a lot of GLSL shaders through Three.js.
By this, I skipped learning the API of WebGL itself.
Along the way, I still gain a various understanding of WebGL concepts.

However, I'm curious if could gain more benefits from going deeper by learning WebGL API itself?

In other words, Is there any significant room for improvement or optimization if I moved from Three.js to pure WebGL?

---

To be more specific on what I needed to optimize.

I'm currently creating a simple raytracing from fragment shaders on Three.js, Multiple renders pass along the render pipeline.

But I also want to know the benefit of pure WebGL rather than Three.js in general use cases.

Comment: To "close voters", I don't think this is an opinion-based question.

Comment: To be clear I think if a person knows both WebGL and Threejs well enough, He may be able to articulate precisely what could be done in WebGL to gain more performance.

Comment: And this is not an opinion, It's a fact!

Answer (score 1):

First, I never used Three.js, so I can't comment on how it is optimized or not. But, as a general consideration, libraries like Three.js are designed to be generalist and versatile, so, they are, per definition, not optimized. To be clear, They ARE optimized, probably as most as possible, but not optimized for every usages. They do compromises, and implements a lot of intermediary "invisible" mechanisms, routines and objects, to allow multiple scenarios to stay possible through easy way on the "user" side.

So, this depend on your usage of the library. Your shaders may be the real "bottleneck" of your "program", because they are really complexes, and in this case using Three.js or going directly via WebGL will change almost nothing except in the shader loading/compiling part, which is done once at start of the program. In contrary, if you are using a lot of library features, with many objects, many per-frame function calls for transformations, buffer loading, etc... It is possible to increase performances by creating your own optimized routines.

Anyway, learning WebGL stuff will allow you to understands how things work in the background, in certain level however. In my point of view,  there is always a benefit to learn how to do without library, you learn the reality behind the library, and being able to create your own library. Once you know WebGL, tou can, for example, more easily jump to OpenGL, then maybe (if you are really brave) Vuklan.